# Calendar Month and Displaying 4th Day in Red in PHP (Loop, Date, HTML Display Font Red)

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a simple loop of the days in the month of that year. So I'm using a for loop in PHP. I assigned a date April 2013, $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2013). I also determined the numbers of days in that month, $days = date("t", $date). And then I did the loop using for loop so that for ($i = 1; $i <= $d1; $i++) it'll display all the days in the month of April 2013, which is 30 days (output: 1, 2, 3,  **4**, 5....30). I'd like to display this in  HTML so that it'll look like a calendar month of April 2013 (which I can figure out later). However, I think I have this "writer's block" per se (or programming block so on). I want to display the so that when $i = 4, displays separately with a red color indicating that it is a special day. This is my main thing I'm stuck with. My code is as follows:

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2013);
$days =  date("t", $date);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) { echo $i; } // except when $i = 4, echoes it as red/bold
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. do you know how to make something red in html? 2. do you know how to work with loops?

Comment: Yes that's easy that I'm not worried about. I just want the loop to echo a consecutive numbers of the days in the month except when $i = 4 spits it <font color="red">$i2</font> then the rest regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2013);
    $days =  date("t", $date);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) { 

         if(($i % 4))
          { 
            echo '<span style="color: #f00; font-weight: bold;">'.$i.'</span>';
           } else { echo $i; } 
 }
```

Comment: This works but corrected your if statement $i == 4... Thank you!

Comment: I was trying to say thank you by clicking the up arrow but I'm new here It won't let me so... Thanks Jay Bahtt, brbcoding and all!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should be what you're after...

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2013);
$days =  date("t", $date);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) { 
if($i % 4 == 0){
    echo "<div style='color: red'>" . $i . "</div>";
}
else{
    echo $i;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... Didn't work... but closed ... I was trying to do an if statement inside where if $i = 4 print <font color="red"> etc else echo $i... but gave me infinite loop...

Comment: Hello brbcoding... I ran it it outputs: 123 then 4 in red then 567, then 8 in red, 91011, then 12 in red.... I just needed the #4 in red. But yeah in general this works too. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I see... I thought you were looking for every fourth element.